# Find if a hash in Python has only values of None

Tags: python, hash

Does anyone know a better way of finding if a hash in Python has only None values than `len([entry for entry in my_hash.values() if entry is not None]) > 0`? 
I couldn't find something more standard than that and it seems like there should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
all(entry is None for entry in my_hash.values())
```

This will short-circuit upon hitting the first non-`None` value so you don't have to necessarily evaluate all the items. Since `None` is falsey you could simplify this to

```
not any(my_hash.values())
```

unless some of your values have other falsey items (like `0`, `''`, etc)

Comment: The OP is trying to determine if all values *are* `None`.  Your `all` command will return True if *none* of the entries are `None`.

Comment: Also, use `my_hash.itervalues()` in Python 2 to avoid constructing the entire list of values before you start examining them.

Comment: I can have other falsey items, so the second option doesn't work for me, but the first one works great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
all(i for i in my_hash.values())
```

will return False if there is a None, and True if there isn't

Comment: This would return False is any value is falsey, not just for a None

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, I don't want if there is "a" None, but if they're "all" None.